I cannot fetch the data from viewmodel in ASP.NET Core MVC. My values for "input-asp-for" looks null in my view. How can I fix this problem?
First Image Description
Second Image Description
When I go to the view, I see some input asp-for fields as null, even though they aren't null. In ViewModel, the reference from other models are given properly, I don't know where the mistake is located. I am trying to take some data which are given in the login(name, phone, etc) as output. My data is not shown in localhost. Also my foreach section does not work.
Controller :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc.Templates.BlazorIdentity.Pages;
using NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types;
using Stripe.Climate;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using static NuGet.Packaging.PackagingConstants;

namespace JewelryWeb.Areas.Customer.Controllers
{
    [Area("admin")]

    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
       
        public OrderController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(string status)
        {
            IEnumerable<OrderHeader> objOrderHeaders = _unitOfWork.OrderHeader.GetAll(includeProperties: "ApplicationUser").ToList();
            switch (status)
            {
                case "pending":
                    objOrderHeaders = objOrderHeaders.Where(u => u.PaymentStatus == SD.PaymentStatusDelayedPayment);
                    break;
                case "inprocess":
                    objOrderHeaders = objOrderHeaders.Where(u => u.OrderStatus == SD.StatusInProcess);
                    break;
                case "completed":
                    objOrderHeaders = objOrderHeaders.Where(u => u.OrderStatus == SD.StatusShipped);
                    break;
                case "approved":
                    objOrderHeaders = objOrderHeaders.Where(u => u.OrderStatus == SD.StatusApproved);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return View(objOrderHeaders);
        }

        public IActionResult Details(int orderId)
        {
            OrderVM orderVM = new()
            {
                OrderHeader = _unitOfWork.OrderHeader.Get(u => u.Id == orderId, includeProperties: "ApplicationUser"),
                OrderDetail = _unitOfWork.OrderDetail.GetAll(u => u.OrderHeaderId == orderId, includeProperties: "Product")
            };

            return View(orderVM);
        }
    }
}

ViewModel:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jewelry.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class OrderVM
    {
        public OrderHeader? OrderHeader { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable <OrderDetail> ?OrderDetail { get; set; }
        public Product ?Product { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ?ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}

OrderDetail Model:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jewelry.Models
{
    public class OrderDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int OrderHeaderId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OrderHeaderId")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public OrderHeader OrderHeader { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
}

OrderHeader Model:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jewelry.Models
{
    public class OrderHeader
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public ApplicationUser? ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ShippingDate { get; set; }
        public double OrderTotal { get; set; }
        public string? OrderStatus { get; set; }
        public string? PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public string? TrackingNumber { get; set; }
        public string? Carrier { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
        public DateOnly PaymentDueDate { get; set; }

        public string? SessionId { get; set; }
        public string? PaymentIntentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? StreetAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? State { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? PostalCode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int PostalCode1 { get; set; }

    }
}

View:
@model OrderVM

<form method="post">
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-dark text-light ml-0">
                <div class="container row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-none d-md-block col-md-6 pb-1">
                        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> &nbsp; Order Summary
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-2 text-right">
                        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-outline-info form-control btn-sm">Back to Orders</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container rounded p-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 pb-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                                    <span class="text-primary">PickUp Details:</span>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Name</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    @if(User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin)) 
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.Name" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="OrderHeader.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.Name" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    }
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Phone</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.PhoneNumber" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="OrderHeader.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.PhoneNumber" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Address</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.StreetAddress" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="OrderHeader.StreetAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.StreetAddress" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">City</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.City" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="OrderHeader.City" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.City"readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">State</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.State" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="OrderHeader.State" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.State" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Zip Code</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.PostalCode" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="OrderHeader.PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.PostalCode" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Email</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.ApplicationUser.Email" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Order Date</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                        <input value="@Model.OrderHeader?.OrderDate.ToShortDateString()" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Carrier</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.Carrier" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                     
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.Carrier" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Tracking</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                                    {
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.TrackingNumber" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                         
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            <input asp-for="OrderHeader.TrackingNumber" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Shipping Date</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                        <input value="@Model.OrderHeader?.ShippingDate.ToShortDateString()" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />

                                </div>
                            </div>

                                @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                                {
                                    <div class="row my-1">
                                        <div class="col-3">Session ID</div>
                                        <div class="col-9">
                                                <input asp-for="OrderHeader.SessionId" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />


                                               
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row my-1">
                                        <div class="col-3">Payment Intent ID</div>
                                        <div class="col-9">

                                                <input asp-for="OrderHeader.PaymentIntentId"  readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                  </div>  
                                }
                         
                                <div class="row my-1">

                                    @if(Model.OrderHeader?.SessionId == null)
                                    {
                                        <div class="col-3">Payment Due Date</div>
                                        <div class="col-9">
                                                <input asp-for="@Model.OrderHeader.?PaymentDueDate.ToShortDateString()"readonly type="text" class="form-control" />

                                        </div>
                                    }
                                   
                                 else{
                                <div class="col-3">Payment Date</div>
                                    <div class="col-9">
                                        <input asp-for="@Model.OrderHeader.PaymentDate.ToShortDateString()" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />

                                    </div>
                                 }
                            </div>
                            <div class="row my-1">
                                <div class="col-3">Payment Status</div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                        <input asp-for="OrderHeader.PaymentStatus" readonly type="text" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning form-control my-1" value="Update Order Details" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 offset-lg-1">
                            <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                                <span class="text-primary">Order Summary</span>
                            </h4>
                            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary form-control my-2">Order Status - @Model.OrderHeader?.OrderStatus</label>

                            <ul class="list-group mb-3">
                                @foreach (var detail in Model.OrderDetail)
                                {
                                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
                                        <div class="row container">
                                            <div class="col-8">

                                                <h6 class="my-0 text-primary">@detail.Product.Title</h6>
                                                <small class="text-muted">Price : @detail.Price.ToString("c")</small><br />
                                                <small class="text-muted">Quantity : @detail.Count</small>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-4 text-end">
                                                <p class="text-success">@((detail.Count * detail.Price).ToString("c"))</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                }
                                <li class="list-group-item bg-primary">
                                    <div class="row container">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <h5 class="text-white">TOTAL </h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6 text-end">
                                            <h5 class="text-white">@Model.OrderHeader?.OrderTotal.ToString("c")</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control my-1" value="Pay Now" />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control my-1" value="Start Processing" />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control my-1" value="Ship Order" />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger form-control my-1" value="Cancel Order" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

I tried to declare some fields as nullable and added a new migration but it didn't change at all. I was expecting it to be fixed, and I also looked for the SQL database, the values appears there. It is not null.

Maybe we can try to add this line @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers before @model OrderVM. I deduce it's due to taghelper didn't work.
Your page loaded well and just no value in the input box, so that it might result from no data was queried out from database, I mean codes below doesn't get data. You might debug your code to check it.
OrderVM orderVM = new()
            {
                OrderHeader = _unitOfWork.OrderHeader.Get(u => u.Id == orderId, includeProperties: "ApplicationUser"),
                OrderDetail = _unitOfWork.OrderDetail.GetAll(u => u.OrderHeaderId == orderId, includeProperties: "Product")
            };

If the model was set data correctly, we can see whether the taghelper worked or not because I noticed that you have [Area] in your controller and I faced the same issue before. In this case, we can press F12 in the browser to see the rendered HTML elements, whether the asp-for is still existed in the page. If so, then let's add the code I shared at the beginning into the View, or adding another _ViewImports.cshtml in the Area folder.
============= My Test =======================
Could you pls help confirm whether your orderVM has data bind to it? And could you please press F12 in the browser to see whether there's any exception message?
public IActionResult Details(int orderId)
{
    OrderVM orderVM = new OrderVM
    {
        OrderHeader = new OrderHeader {Name="order header name", PaymentDate=DateTime.Now },
        OrderDetail = new List<OrderDetail> { new OrderDetail { Count = 12}, new OrderDetail { Count = 13 } },
    };

    return View(orderVM);
}


=========================
If we have any error in the client side, we shall see error in the console window.

If taghelper didn't work, we can see asp-for still exist in html element. The first screenshot below is the test result that I comment the taghelper, while the second one has @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers in the view.



I tried this but it didn't work, I also had taghelpers on my viewimports sections. Thank you. Do you have any other possible solution?

Could you pls help confirm whether you had data bind to the ViewModel? And could you pls help confirm which field should display value in the page? We need a minimal sample for testing the issue. because your codes looks good and the view already rendered correctly.

Your codes worked well in my side when I manually OrderHeader = new OrderHeader and OrderDetail = new List<OrderDetail>, the input text has data inside it.

I added the taghelper into viewimports, but didn't create a new viewimports file because I already have it on the areas folder. I pressed FN+F12 and attached the regarding picture on my description. Where should I look for the error? By the way what do you mean by data bind, do you mean that do I have an existing data for the OrderDetail/OrderHeader? I have them already which appears on SQL. The details section that you give does not work for me :(

@BüşraNur I updated my post above with the test result. Could you pls just add the taghelper in the view? I also created a new viewimports file in Areas/Customer folder which also worked for me if I add taghelper in thie viewimports file.

Thank you that worked, but what if I want to fetch the existing data that exists in the previous records, can I take them also to the input fields?  I shared this issue on the latest picture. I marked them with yellow marker.

I noticed that you have an Index view which containing a table, and maybe click one of the row will redirect to the corresponding Detail view. Then do you mean you want to bring the existing data in the table row to the Details view so that you don't need to query again? If so, I'm afraid it's not a good idea. Firstly, asp.net core web app renders the html in the server side so that what we have is cshtml but not html, cshtml can't run directly in browser, so that we can't do the redirect in the client side via window.herf, we have to follow the routing rule to visit the Details Controller

We can certainly try to pass the data from the view to the controller so that inside the Details action method, we don't need to query again, but this will bring much more pressure through the network which is not a good practice, so that we'd better to query the database based on the orderId like what you do now. Pls correct me if I didn't understand your issue.

I actually justified that row, it will redirect me to the detail page. Yes, I meant that way. Then I can look for the Youtube for other solutions about e-commerce apps, how did they fetch, maybe there is another way to create a order summary page. Thank you so much.

Thanks for your confirmation, we could only do it like this when using razor pages(cshtml). Maybe we could use some other structure. But I think if we are just writing a sample, cshtml is good and enough. When the application become bigger and bigger, maybe we will go to use frontend-backend-seperately structure, and this might make the application to be rewrite completely. Do you have any other questions in this case now?

You're welcome, thanks to you for your support. But your method is also a good option to create a sample data, it's a good idea. Yes, that happened to me, I have a project for my software development course which is deadlined at the end of this week. This project is about that. No, I don't have other questions. Thanks for your help.

Thank you for your confirmation! It's a development course then I think an mvc app should be the best option.

You're welcome! I hope it will be completed as soon as possible.
